# Lotus Connection API issue

Tags: api, lotus, ibm-connections

I am working on Lotus Connection. I wanted to fetch the values in AboutMe section and Background section of profiles using the Lotus Connections API.

Is it possible to do so. I had gone through the wiki and other help , but could 
not find any solution

Please help if any one got a solution

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution for this. There is no api specifically designed for 
updating the aboutMe and Background Information in Lotus Connection.
One who had to update it programmatically has to connect to Lotus Connection
backend(Database) and write an update query to update the prof_description (AboutMe)
and prof_experience(Background) fields of employee table in PeopleDB schema

Answer (score 0):

There is an api for updating those fields, I don't know what version of Connections you are using but I linked to the 3.0 public [API](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/lcwiki.nsf/xpDocViewer.xsp?lookupName=Lotus+Connections+3+documentation#action=openDocument&res_title=Updating_profile_entries_lc3&content=pdcontent)

What fields you are looking to update are for the "About Me" section the field "description" and for the "Background" you want "experience" field.